# A simple question about special relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

[image]

Assume that the table moves with the velocity $\vec{v} = v\hat{i}$.

For the observer at $x=0$, the event at $(ct',x')=(0,k)$ is observed at $(t,x)=(k\gamma\beta, k\gamma)$ using Lorentz's transformation $L(v) = \gamma\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1&\beta\\ \beta&1
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$.

For the observer at $x=4$, I'm not confident about my answer. For him, the event at $(ct',x')=(0,k) (k=1,2,3)$ is probably observed at $(ct,x)=(-(4-k)\gamma\beta, (4-k)\gamma)$ using the Lorentz's transformation $L(-v)=\gamma\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1&-\beta\\ -\beta&1
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$.

Is my answer for (a) correct?

Comment: Why would the table be moving?

Comment: If the frame of the firecrackers doesn't move, what is moving? I'm sorry, but I can't get what this problem is asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use Lorenz factor to answer (a). You only need to notice that light propagates at c and that firecrackers go off simultaneously (relative to table and to stationary observer at either end of the table). Then observer at x = 0 will notice light from the first firecracker after 1/c. (t = s/v that is after 1/c. The second after 2/c.)

The second question is a bit more tricky. What is simultaneous to one observer (call him stationary ) is not simultaneous to another observer moving relative to the first one. Here you will need to employ Special Relativity.

Comment: I got it! I was thinking in a too complicated way. For (b), does the time passage of the frame moving toward the observer look faster for the observer compared with his frame?

Comment: I think this video has a very good explanation: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wteiuxyqtoM